# SQL Server to Postgresql - Database migration - Tool issues

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I am trying to migrate from SQL Server to postgresql. I am using the tool [dbmigration.net](http://fishcodelib.com/DBMigration.htm). Here it generates scripts without foreign key constraints.

Is there a way to get these constraints generated as well? Or is there any other tool which can do the same?

I am looking for only free ones

Thanks in advance
Rathi